# How to merge two test into one RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Both the last two test work individually...but when both are set to run (non pending) I get problems.

question: can I create a test that merges the two into one? How would this look?(yes, I am new to rspec)

```
require_relative '../spec_helper'

# the universe is vast and infinite....and...it is empty
describe "tic tac toe game" do
  context "the game class" do

    before (:each) do
      player_h = Player.new("X")
      player_c = Player.new("O")
      @game = Game.new(player_h, player_c)
    end

   it "method drawgrid must return a 3x3 game grid" do
      @game.drawgrid.should eq("\na #{$thegrid[:a1]}|#{$thegrid[:a2]}|#{$thegrid[:a3]} \n----------\nb #{$thegrid[:b1]}|#{$thegrid[:b2]}|#{$thegrid[:b3]} \n----------\nc #{$thegrid[:c1]}|#{$thegrid[:c2]}|#{$thegrid[:c3]} \n----------\n  1 2 3 \n")
      @game.drawgrid
   end
   #FIXME - last two test here - how to merge into one?
   it "play method must display 3x3 game grid" do
      STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).and_return("\na #{$thegrid[:a1]}|#{$thegrid[:a2]}|#{$thegrid[:a3]} \n----------\nb #{$thegrid[:b1]}|#{$thegrid[:b2]}|#{$thegrid[:b3]} \n----------\nc #{$thegrid[:c1]}|#{$thegrid[:c2]}|#{$thegrid[:c3]} \n----------\n  1 2 3 \n").with("computer move")
      @game.play
    end
    it "play method must display 3x3 game grid" do
      STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with("computer move")
      @game.play
    end
  end
end
```

just for info here is the code containing the play method

```
require_relative "player"
#
#Just a Tic Tac Toe game class
class Game
  #create players
  def initialize(player_h, player_c)
    #bring into existence the board and the players
    @player_h = player_h
    @player_c = player_c
    #value hash for the grid lives here
    $thegrid = {
        :a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ",
        :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ",
        :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "
    }
    #make a global var for drawgrid which is used by external player class
    $gamegrid = drawgrid

  end
  #display grid on console
  def drawgrid

    board = "\n"
    board << "a #{$thegrid[:a1]}|#{$thegrid[:a2]}|#{$thegrid[:a3]} \n"
    board << "----------\n"
    board << "b #{$thegrid[:b1]}|#{$thegrid[:b2]}|#{$thegrid[:b3]} \n"
    board << "----------\n"
    board << "c #{$thegrid[:c1]}|#{$thegrid[:c2]}|#{$thegrid[:c3]} \n"
    board << "----------\n"
    board << "  1 2 3 \n"
    return board

  end
  #start the game
  def play
    #draw the board
    puts drawgrid
    #external call to player class
    @player = @player_c.move_computer("O")
  end
end

player_h = Player.new("X")
player_c = Player.new("O")


game = Game.new(player_h, player_c)
game.play
```

UPDATE - TESTING ERROR OUTPUT
Just for completeness sake....here is the full output from running rspec spec...

```
    gideon@thefonso ~/Documents/ca_ruby/rubytactoe (now-with-rspec)$ rspec spec

    a  | |  
    ----------
    b  | |  
    ----------
    c  | |  
    ----------
      1 2 3 
    computer move

    tic tac toe game
      the game class
        method drawgrid must return a 3x3 game grid

    An error occurred in an after(:each) hook
      RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: (#<IO:0x007f948406fcf0>).puts(any args)
        expected: 1 time
        received: 0 times
      occurred at /Users/gideon/Documents/ca_ruby/rubytactoe/spec/game_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

        play method must display 3x3 game grid (FAILED - 1)

    An error occurred in an after(:each) hook
      RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: (#<IO:0x007f948406fcf0>).puts("computer move")
        expected: 1 time
        received: 0 times
      occurred at /Users/gideon/Documents/ca_ruby/rubytactoe/spec/game_spec.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

        play method must display 3x3 game grid (FAILED - 2)

    tic tac toe game
      the player class
        must have a human player X
        must have a computer player O

    Failures:

      1) tic tac toe game the game class play method must display 3x3 game grid
         Failure/Error: STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).and_return("\na #{$thegrid[:a1]}|#{$thegrid[:a2]}|#{$thegrid[:a3]} \n----------\nb #{$thegrid[:b1]}|#{$thegrid[:b2]}|#{$thegrid[:b3]} \n----------\nc #{$thegrid[:c1]}|#{$thegrid[:c2]}|#{$thegrid[:c3]} \n----------\n  1 2 3 \n").with("computer move")
         NoMethodError:
           undefined method `with' for #<Proc:0x007f9484341168>
         # ./spec/game_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

      2) tic tac toe game the game class play method must display 3x3 game grid
         Failure/Error: @game.play
           #<IO:0x007f948406fcf0> received :puts with unexpected arguments
             expected: ("computer move")
                  got: ("\na  | |  \n----------\nb  | |  \n----------\nc  | |  \n----------\n  1 2 3 \n")
         # ./lib/game.rb:37:in `puts'
         # ./lib/game.rb:37:in `play'
         # ./spec/game_spec.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

    Finished in 0.00457 seconds
    5 examples, 2 failures

    Failed examples:

    rspec ./spec/game_spec.rb:17 # tic tac toe game the game class play method must display 3x3 game grid
    rspec ./spec/game_spec.rb:21 # tic tac toe game the game class play method must display 3x3 game grid
    gideon@thefonso ~/Documents/ca_ruby/rubytactoe (now-with-rspec)$
```

Answer (score 1):

Questions should include what *kind* of "problems" you get; they help diagnose what's gone wrong.

Here's *an* answer, with a caveat afterwards; there are other ways.

```ruby
it "play method must display 3x3 game grid" do
  STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with("\na #{$thegrid[:a1]}|#{$thegrid[:a2]}|#{$thegrid[:a3]} \n----------\nb #{$thegrid[:b1]}|#{$thegrid[:b2]}|#{$thegrid[:b3]} \n----------\nc #{$thegrid[:c1]}|#{$thegrid[:c2]}|#{$thegrid[:c3]} \n----------\n  1 2 3 \n").twice.ordered
  STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with("computer move").once.ordered

  @game.play
  @game.play
end
```

The caveat: the way you're testing now will be impossible to sustain. I likely would *not* continue down the path of checking output during move testing, rather I'd test output separately, but isolate move mechanics so you can check, say, an array value, or a flag indicating whose move it is, and so on.

You'll also want to decide if you really want to test sequential moves, as opposed to move calculation logic. Sequential moves require either irritating test constructs like the above, or enforcing test order, or otherwise making sure the sequence of moves is correct.

It may make more sense to rethink what, specifically, you're testing, and when.

Comment: ahhh yes and that is the question..what,specifically to test and when. :) I'm very new to RSpec so I'm going to try to keep it as basic as possible but knowing that I am going in a "basic" direction is impossible to know given my newness to it. Yet another layer of difficulty. Thank you for the response.